# is not abstract and does not override abstract method apply(Object) in Function

Tags: java, selenium

I want to wait until a js script return true, the code I am using is not compiling and throwing error

```
is not abstract and does not override abstract method apply(Object) in Function
```

here is the code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        boolean isFound = wait.until(new ExpectedCondition(){ //here ERROR
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d){
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
                return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return true");
            }
        });
```

I tried to copy code from 
http://www.tarnowski.se/2011/09/11/converting-selenium-waitforcondition-to-webdriverwait/

Comment: Well, it does _not_ override `apply(Object)`.

Comment: What is confusing about the message that tells you exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Make it override `apply(Object)`...

Comment: I am new to Java, not sure how to fix this code snippet.

Comment: how to make it override?

Comment: You need to change the method signature or create a new one with the signature. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d){
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
            return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return true");
        }
```

try

```
        public Boolean apply(Object d){
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
            return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return true");
        }
```

The Function class/interface expects a method with this signature in its subclasses that you create.

If there's a `raw types` warning, perhaps `new ExpectedCondition<WebDriver>(){ ...` is what you're expected to do?

Comment: thanks.... Fixed, that was all, not sure why negative rating and a lot of comments just to confuse new comers.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" could explain the downvote (not mine). The comments should direct you to the solution, not to confuse you.

Comment: We are here to help, not to hand out solutions (give a man a fish...)

Comment: @coure2011, you still forgot to accept this answer ;). By the way, a nice example of the usefullness of `@Override`.